# How can I delete data using AJAX in REST API (SLIM FRAME)

Tags: slim, http-delete

I want to delete user using REST API. I try to use

```
 id = $(this).attr('rel');
    $.ajax({
        url: App.url+'/allusers/users/'+id, 
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);    
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is DELETE HTTP method used to delete in REST.

Comment: I got out the solution and above link is working file for me.